# Place visual selection inside of a variable inside of a command

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode

I want to write a command that works with a visual selection, so I wrote something like this:

```
command! -range Foo
    \ exec "norm \"ay" |
    \ echo "[" . @a . "]"
```

hoping that it would take the visual selection and put it into the @a register, then I could use the @a register as normal, but there's never anything in the @a register. How do I get the visual selection into a variable? It should work with block mode visual selection as well as the normal mode.

Comment: If I use `yank a` it seems like it just yanks the first line of the visual selection into the register, I want all of the lines.

Comment: Oh, yes, you need something like `command! -range Foo <line1>,<line2>yank a ...`  (I'm not in front of the right computer ... my folks don't have Vim LOL ... so I can't test but it's something like that.) I think this only works for _linewise_ selections, though.

Answer (score 1):

I see now the `:normal` command will exit the visual selection mode temporarily, so if you wanted to get the visual selection, you have to reselect it in the command by using `gv`, as in `:execute "normal gv\"ay"`.

This would require the command be used when there's a visual selection active; if you used it with the default range, it would select the previous visual selection, which might not be what the user was expecting. Instead it should use the `<line1>` and `<line2>` replacements the command defines for you; however, these do not work with visual block mode.

Comment: You could have your command simply ignore the range and use `gv` unconditionally... But it seems a Visual mode mapping using `xnoremap` is probably more appropriate here.